# SSRS URL Changes while navigating

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I am trying to track down the root cause of this issue I keep seeing.

We have SSRS running with a custom URL like https://reporting.companyname.com/reports.

When I connect to that address I can login and see reports.  If I progress to a report and click manage I get the report detail and the list of properties on the side screen.

Now if I click on data source it gives me a failure to load page and I notice that the URL in the address bar is http://reporting.companyname.com/reports .

If I put an "s" in that URL the page loads.  I am trying to figure out how I can fix this.

Any ideas would be helpful.

SSRS 2008 R2 enterprise edition

Comment: The data source page is the only one not https?

Comment: No, any of the settings tabs.  Subscriptions, data source and other.

Comment: What is configured in the URLReservations sections of your <install path>\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config file for URL's? You might also want to go into the Reporting Services Configuration Manager tool to see what is configured in the Report Manager URL/Advanced section, as that's a little more user-friendly than reviewing the config. Curious if there's a mismatch for the SSL vs non-SSL identities for the Report Manager settings. Also, do you know what exact URL the SSL cert is reserved for?

Answer (score 1):

The URL to manage the reports is different than the URL to execute the reports (the RDLs files)

You can check it in the Report Configuration.

Regards,
Martín G